# necessary bank information to receive wire transfer from abroad

Tags: bank-account, transfer

One of my clients will send money to my bank account in my country S.Korea from his bank account in E.U. country.

I sent the bank info (A/C No., SWIFT CODE, My and Bank Address), h'ever, the party asked me to send additional info such as

- GLOBAL SERVER IP
- GLOBAL SERVER ID
- RECEIVING SERVER ID
- WTS SERVER
- LOGON SERVER

My bank said to me they don't have any Idea about these info and said Bank SWIFT code and a/c No. are enough to receive money from abroad.

What can I do for this  problem?

Comment: The named pieces of information don't make any sense for a bank transfer. I can't tell you exactly what, but something is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Those fields are used in a bank-to-bank transfers that do not use SWIFT. SWIFT is a messaging system, however with the fields you have listed, banks can exchange messages directly without having to use SWIFT.

Your bank may not support bank-to-bank transfers, in which you need to notify your client that it needs to be a SWIFT transfer.